# is there tool to build distributed search techniques?

Tags: distributed-system, distributed-algorithm, distributed-apps

Is there any tool, program, framework or anything that can help me in building distributed search techniques and evaluating the performance of those techniques.
Any possible help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Algon framework](http://citeseer.uark.edu:8080/citeseerx/viewdoc/versions?doi=10.1.1.136.105), but it seems there's only some references (pdf) left about it:

http://eprints.gla.ac.uk/3650/1/Algon_framework.pdf

They mention in **5 - The Performance Display Tool** that:

> The performance comparison support tool was developed to work with
>   the algorithms already implemented in Algon.

Here's [her contact](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~karen/#five) (author).

Comment: @nebras I believe the tool was developed specifically for that research, and it's probably not available to anyone, so you should [contact Karen - the author of that paper](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~karen/#five) (click in the email icon at the right) in order to know if it's still available. Let me know once you get a reply!